# Getting Software Alien from Terminal

Tags: apt

I used

```
sudo apt-get install alien dpkg-dev debhelper build-essential
```

to get alien package for Terminal in Ubuntu 14.04 . But I got this Error Message and couldn't find a Solution... This is what I got in Terminal,

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dpkg-dev : Depends: libdpkg-perl (= 1.17.5ubuntu5) but 1.17.5ubuntu5.3 is to be installed
            Recommends: fakeroot but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: libalgorithm-merge-perl but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Please help me, I'm still a beginner for Linux...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Comment: No , I saw it and tried almost everything in it... But error Continues...In this error there are some Recommends, How can I handle those ?

Comment: what happens if you try `sudo apt-get -f install`?

Comment: Nothing installed, removed or upgraded... :(

Comment: [link](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/synaptic) - Synaptic Package Manager; I used this Software to Install alien package, I searched Alien Package from it and Tried to Install it... Its Saying "Could not apply Changes, Fix Broken first" ... When I checked the Status of Package it is Saying Broken... How to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Package **`alien`** & `build-essential` are avilable on [main repository for Ubuntu 14.04](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/trusty/main/base/alien).

First of all make sure that you have enabled Main & Universe Repository from Software & Updates:

> The **main** component contains applications that are free software, can be freely redistributed and are fully supported by the Ubuntu team. & The **universe** component is a snapshot of the free, open-source, and Linux world.

[image]

Following command is also helpful to enable main & universe repositories:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main universe"
sudo apt-get update
```

Then install package by:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install alien
```

If you've still problem then **check extra repository you manually added** (from Software & Updates > Other Software) ; **remove/clear** them. And then try `sudo apt-get update` , `sudo apt-get install alien`

*`sudo apt-get install -f` and `sudo dpkg --configure -a` are also helpful for fix dependencies and complete pending configuration.*

Comment: Thank You Very Much... It worked for me... I think it was after adding repository link you mentioned... Thanks...