# How to install Printer Drivers with rpm extension

Tags: drivers, permissions, printing, canon

I have a Canon Pixma P200 and I have downloaded the Linux drivers from their site. I extracted them and I found 4 .rpm files. I decided to open terminal and type in

```
/home/rsbayani/Desktop/cnijfilter-p200series-4.00-1-rpm/packages/cnijfilter-p200series-4.00-1.x86_64.rpm -i
```

but it doesn't work, it just gives me permission denied. I also tried the code below

```
/home/rsbayani/Desktop/cnijfilter-p200series-4.00-1-rpm/packages/cnijfilter-p200series-4.00-1.x86_64.rpm --install
```

But like the one above it, it ssill gives me a permission denied.
I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Any help would be gladly appreciated.

Comment: Which site did you download the drivers from? RPM files are packages for RedHat based systems, you need to download the DEB files if they are available (for debian based systems) then [install them](http://askubuntu.com/q/40779/178596)

Comment: I got them here: http://support-ph.canon-asia.com/contents/PH/EN/0100551401.html There seems to be no DEB files available within the site.

Comment: You may convert `.rpm` packages to `.deb packages`, [check this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/install-an-rpm-package-on-ubuntu-linux/)

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 14.04 Firefox 37, [the download page](http://support-ph.canon-asia.com/contents/PH/EN/0100551401.html) seems to work for me showing:

> ## P200 series IJ Printer Driver Ver. 4.00 for Linux (debian Packagearchive)
>
> - Last Updated : 05-Sep-2013
> - Issue Number : 0100551401
>
> ### OS
>
> ```
> Linux
> ```
>
> ### Outline
>
> This software is a printer driver for printing using the Canon IJ
>   printer.
>   
>   ....
>   *lots of stuff about licenses you probably ought to read*
>   ....
>
> ### System requirements
>
> Ubuntu 13.04(32bit/64bit)
>
> ### Setup instruction
>
> Install the downloaded package archive file as an Administrator
>   following the manual. For how to install and use this software, refer
>   to the instruction manual.
>
> ### File information
>
> ```
> File name : cnijfilter-p200series-4.00-1-deb.tar.gz
> File version : 4.00
> File language : German, English, French, Japanese, Simplified Chinese
> File size : 1,387KB
> ```
>
> [Download Now](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/4/0100005514/01/cnijfilter-p200series-4.00-1-deb.tar.gz)

Once you have downloaded it (it should have the filename `cnijfilter-p200series-4.00-1-deb.tar.gz`), it looks like you have to run the `install.sh` file in the parent directory of the files you extract *(extract all the files from the archive first)*. This probably should install the appropriate `cnijfilter-common_4.00-1` and `cnijfilter-p200series_4.00-1` packages contained within it for you architecture.

If you are still having download issues, try this in terminal

```
wget gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/4/0100005514/01/cnijfilter-p200series-4.00-1-deb.tar.gz    
tar zxvf cnijfilter-p200series-4.00-1-deb.tar.gz
cd cnijfilter-p200series-4.00-1-deb
sudo ./install.sh
rm cnijfilter-p200series-4.00-1-deb.tar.gz
rm -rf cnijfilter-p200series-4.00-1-deb
```

These lines of code will download, extract, install and clean up after the installation

The page says it is for 13.04, they may not work for other releases, in which case try installing the the deb files using `sudo gdebi /PATH/TO/FILE1.deb /PATH/TO/FILE1.deb` - install the amd64 debs if you are using 64bit Ubuntu, and the i386 if you are using 32bit.

You might not be getting this as your internet browser is sending a [User agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) for a OS that uses RPMs or something.

Comment: +1 This, @Roshan Bayani - I know it says its a tar.gz file but if you unzip it you will find the .deb, just click "download now" in this answer, works fine for me

Comment: Nice idea @markkirby - I edited your script a bit as I think only the install script need be run as root. Haven't checked whether it works either, but it probably should :)

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't to sure so I just used a full root shell to cover myself, I did test it, works great, even runs a nice text installer for making sure you have the right .debs

Answer (score 0):

You can use alien to convert .rpm to deb files. If your interested here's a link to help to install this package. [Getting Software Alien from Terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/543549/getting-software-alien-from-terminal).